# How to create single SPRINT across multiple project in JIRA

Tags: jira, agile, sprint

Is it possible to create a Sprint, that has Items in the Backlog picked up from different Jira Projects.? Is it the right practice?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a JIRA board based on a JQL query that joins several projects.

For example, something like:

> project = projectX AND project = projectY AND project = projectZ

Save the JQL into a filter and select the [create board based on filter option](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/create-a-board/).